# Missing \endgroup inserted in tabular

Tags: tables, errors

I have to make a table with nested columns in the first row.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{14}{|c|}{Truth table}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|c|c|c}{Inputs} %error here
 & \multicolumn{10}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}{Outputs}\\
\hline
$A_3$ & $A_2$ & $A_1$ & $A_0$ & $\bar{Y_0}$ & $\bar{Y_1}$ & $\bar{Y_2}$ & $\bar{Y_3}$ & $\bar{Y_4}$ & $\bar{Y_5}$ & $\bar{Y_6}$ & $\bar{Y_7}$ & $\bar{Y_8}$ & $\bar{Y_9}$\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{solution}
```

When trying to compile, it's throwing me the following error on the fifth line of the code showed earlier.

> Missing \endgroup inserted

I have closed the curly brackets. What am I missing?

Comment: Your example ends with `\end{array}` but starts with `\begin{tabular}`. While `tabular` is an `array` effectively this might cause the error; however, your example is a fragment only, we don't know how `solution` is defined

Comment: ... and with `\end{solution}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, that's an older version, it's tabular now, but i still have the same error.

Comment: @marmot, that's from a block started earlier.

Comment: @Cornul11: Well, you should post the code that you're using right from the start, not something that were used 'ages' ago ;-) Also post complete documents, not just fragments

Comment: Your multicolumn commands do not make sense. Replace them by \multicolumn{14}{|c|}{Truth table}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Inputs} 
 & \multicolumn{10}{|c|}{Outputs}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{14}{|c|}{Truth table}\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Inputs} & \multicolumn{10}{c|}{Outputs}\\
    \hline
    $A_3$ & $A_2$ & $A_1$ & $A_0$ & $\bar{Y_0}$ & $\bar{Y_1}$ & $\bar{Y_2}$ & $\bar{Y_3}$ & $\bar{Y_4}$ & $\bar{Y_5}$ & $\bar{Y_6}$ & $\bar{Y_7}$ & $\bar{Y_8}$ & $\bar{Y_9}$\\
    \hline 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work now. Even after analyzing documentation for the \multicolumn command, i didn't notice that we have to mention the format for only one cell.

Comment: With `\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{text}` you're creating a single cell spanning four columns, containing `text` aligned centered and the cell being preceded and followed by a `|`. Since it's a single cell, more than one alignment doesn't make sense.

Comment: @HenkMetselaar, yes, now i get it.

Comment: This answer does not explain how it solves the issue; readers need to diff the answer's code with the question's code.